# How does division work?

Tags: batch-file

I've just started learning batach and I have some problems understanding division. In other languages, when I would do this:

> 25 /= 10

The result would be 2.

But in batch, when I do 25 /= 10, the result is still 25. Why is that? How can I get the "2" out of 25 when I divide by 10?

Comment: your line of code makes sense in no language… basically `/=` means divide and assign to left value, whereas you show the left value being a number.

Comment: In what language is that valid code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you show makes no sense. `25/=10' tries to divide and assign to the left side, which is an integer.

I think what you're actually trying to do is more like this:

```
set test=25
set /a test/=10
```

If that's the case, this works perfectly fine:

```
@echo off
set test=25
@echo Test is %test%
set /a test/=10
@echo Now Test is %test%
pause
```

The output is:

```
D:\TempFiles>divtest
Test is 25
Now Test is 2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the variable names with %% to get their value.

So here's how:

```
@echo off
set num1=25
set num2=10
set /a result=%num1%/%num2%
echo num1=%num1%
echo num2=%num2%
echo %result%
```

Output:

```
> foo.bat
num1=25
num2=10
2
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But it is not necessary when using SET /A. Read the documentation. `SET /A RESULT=NUM1/NUM2` works just as well.